# .hashchange without jumping to anchor tag?

Tags: jquery, plugins, anchor, hashtag

I'm using Ben Alman's [Hashchange](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) plugin and I have the code successfully switching up the class of specified divs.

What I can't figure out is how to get it to stop jumping to the anchor tags.. I want it to stay wherever the user is currently positioned scroll-wise.

here's my code...

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){
$(function(){
$('.eventselected').removeClass('eventselected');
$(location.hash).addClass('eventselected');

});
});

$(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );
```

The situation is that I want the class added when the user comes to the page from an external link and when a link is clicked while on the parent page. Just don't want it to jump!

the link's class is `.side-eventmore`

I've tried revising my code with this... but is still doesn't work...

```
$( ".side-eventmore" ).click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var hash = $(this).attr("href").replace('events.cfm', '') || 'blank';
document.location.hash = hash;  
});

$(window).hashchange( function(ev){
ev.preventDefault();
$(function(){
$('.eventselected').removeClass('eventselected');
$(location.hash).addClass('eventselected');
});

});

$(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, figured it out.

What I had to end up doing was manually change each of my affected div's id's to the hashtag plus "-id", but kept the links to just the hashtag sans "-id" so..

```
<div id="#hash-id"></div>
<a href="#hash">link</a>
```

then in the code I applied the new class to only #hash-id ... like so...

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){

var selectid = location.hash;
selectid += '-id';

$(function(){
$('.eventselected').removeClass('eventselected');
$(selectid).addClass('eventselected');
});

});

$(window).trigger( 'hashchange' );
```